# Phonegap Google AdMob interstitial add watched identification

Tags: android, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I am developing phonegap android application where I have implemented Google `admob` Currently I am displaying banner ads at the bottom of the page. For that I have taken help of [phonegap-admob-demo](https://github.com/kunal95/phonegap-admob-demo)

You can check the `Js` code for displaying ad at `index.html` page [link for index.html](https://github.com/kunal95/phonegap-admob-demo/blob/master/index.html)

By using this code I am able to display Banner as well as Interstitial ads successfully.

=======

Now  I want to check whether user has successfully watched whole Interstitial ad. Depending upon that I want to give extra time for user to use the app. So basically I want run specific functionality when and only when whole interstitial add is watched.

How can I implement that? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Using the plugin at https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova you can test if an interstitial has been shown with the [events](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Events):

```
document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, function (e) {
    console.log(e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.BANNER ? "Banner" : "Interstitial");
    console.log("Called when an ad is received.");
});

document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdOpened, function (e) {
    console.log(e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.BANNER ? "Banner" : "Interstitial");
    console.log("Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen. Please note that onPause event is raised when an interstitial is shown.");
});

document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, function (e) {
    console.log(e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.BANNER ? "Banner" : "Interstitial");
    console.log("Called when the user is about to return to the application after clicking on an ad. Please note that onResume event is raised when an interstitial is closed.");
});

document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLeftApplication, function (e) {
    console.log(e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.BANNER ? "Banner" : "Interstitial");
    console.log("Called when an ad leaves the application (e.g., to go to the browser).");
});
```